# Image flickers in ListView datatemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

could someone tell me, how can I avoid image flickering in Datatemplate? Everytime I change the source through binding (MVVM pattern), the image in ListViewItem flickers. For other images in app I've used ImageOpened event in code-behind. But I can't be used when I have DataTemplate.

**EDIT:**

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactItemDataTemplate" x:DataType="contactData:Contact">
        <Grid MinHeight="48">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MainImage" Source="{x:Bind ImageStatusUri, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,8,12,8">

                </Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Nickname, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" StrokeThickness="0.4" Height="0.4"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="#D1D3D4"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

type *Contact* implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

**EDIT2:**

WriteableBitmap is working, but I have 3 images with scaling factors 100, 200 and 400. It always choose the image with scale 400. When I use normal binding no WriteableBitmap, it take image with scale 100.

Comment: Add some code, please, to let us inspect it.

Comment: I've added some code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is for you to sub-class the Image control, overriding the Source property and controlling the transition from one image to another with a flicker-less flow. Learn here: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-controls-14482

Comment: The link is expired, any new solution?